# Getting error on Google App Script, but I don't know why

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm using this person's work as a source, which I know is a little outdated, but I imagine this should work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49988473/21345154

Here is a condensed version of my code:

```
let Form = FormApp.openByUrl("########");
let allItems = Form.getItems();
let itemIndex = 2;//This is where I start and I am moving questions in the Form to the correct spot using itemIndex.

//Lots of stuff in the middle

let newItem = allItems[itemIndex+k].duplicate().setTitle(studentName);
    //Don't worry about the index--it's finding a valid element.
Form.moveItem(newItem, itemIndex++);//Crashes here for some reason
```

It keeps crashing with this error message:
`Exception: The parameters (FormApp.ListItem,number) don't match the method signature for FormApp.Form.moveItem.`

But I use this exact same method to move elsewhere:

```
let item = itemFinderFunction(studentName);//abbreviated for simplicity
item.setTitle(studentName);
Form.moveItem(item, itemIndex++);
```

and this code runs successfully every time.

I have tried converting the newItem to a List item (using .asListItem()), which doesn't change anything.  I can't convert it to any other type.  I don't understand what's wrong or missing.  The newItem is an item because all of the methods are working on it.  The Form generates a new question, but never moves it because of this issue.  I can't figure out what's going on.

What I really want to know is why doesn't this work?  With my particular Form and the specific question I know that it's running this line for (because I made it specifically to test this part of my code) it isn't working.  However, I tried matching what the original poster did EXACTLY and nested the method call inside of an IF statement, like so

```
let newItem = allItems[itemIndex+k].duplicate().setTitle(studentName);
if (newItem.getIndex() != itemIndex) {
  Form.moveItem(newItem, itemIndex++);
}
```

This did not change the issue.  So what's causing the issue?

Comment: itemFinderFunction is undefined

Comment: The function does not actually exist. My code executes a large block of code to do what it does. I did not present the code (so I said it was abbreviated for simplicity). Are you trying to accomplish something specific?

Comment: It is difficult to resolve a problem that we can't create.  So please provide a [mcve] so that we can create the problem.  What you provide is not reproducible.  So we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known issue with this method.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175979141?pli=1

This is my preferred option:

```
form.moveItem(form.getItemById(newItem.getId()), 0);
```